# Call methods on UIButton objects in NSMutableArray Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, nsmutablearray

I have an array called buttons which consists of UIButton objects. I populate it as follows:

```
for (int i=0; i<self.numButtons; i++) {
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(xCoord-40, y, 80, 20);
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTag:i];
    [self.buttons addObject:button];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
    y+= 45;
}
```

The action for these buttons is buttonAction. This action is supposed to change the color of the selected button. Here is how I have it implemented:

```
-(void) buttonAction:(id)sender{
    int num = (int)[sender tag];
    [[self.buttons objectAtIndex:num] setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSLog(@"%@", [self.buttons objectAtIndex:buttonClicked].titleLabel.text);
}
```

The result is that there is no color change. Even when I try to NSLog the title of the button it returns (null). So my question is how can I fix this but also how do I call methods on objects inside arrays? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `self.buttons` is probably `nil`.

Answer (score 4):

All evidence points to `self.buttons` being `nil`. Did you ever initialize it?

Somewhere you need a line like:

```
self.buttons = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Of course you could use the `sender` parameter to your `buttonAction:` method:

```
- (void)buttonAction:(UIButton *)button {
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Note the change in the parameter.

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I forgot to initialize it

Comment: You wouldn't be the first person to make that mistake. But unless you have a need to access the buttons elsewhere, there is no need for the array.

Comment: @rmaddy is right. The UIView keeps a collection of all UI elements added as subviews. To get all elements on your view simple call self.view.subviews from inside your view controller.

Answer (score 0):

I like to do this. Don't forget to use IBAction. It will help if you decide to use a nib or storyboard.

```
-(IBAction) buttonAction:(id)sender{
    [((UIButton*)sender) setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal]
    NSLog(@"%@", ((UIButton*)sender).titleLabel.text)
}
```